# React not rendering element if async call for data takes too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, codesandbox

I'm grabbing user data from an API. The API call takes a while. But even when the frontend gets the response, React never finishes rendering the component.

I can replicate this behavior with `setTimeout`.
A small timeout like `7ms` will work, but if I use a larger timeout like `700ms` `<h1>Text rendered!</h1>` doesn't display.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => setUsers({ data: ["user1", "user2", "user3"] }), 700);
  }, []);
```

In the debugger I can see that the flow seems to be working

1. The frontend receives the response, and calls `setUser`.
2. This triggers the second `useEffect` callback which updates `users`.
3. This re-renders the component, and `users && users.updated` is true, but then ***`<h1>Text rendered!</h1>` doesn't render for some reason.***

Oddly though, on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shadow-yfg61?file=/src/App.js), I get completely different behavior: `<h1>Text rendered!</h1>` never renders, even if I use a small timeout like 1ms, or even if I just use `setUsers` with **no `setTimeout`**. And on my local environment, sometimes `700ms` does work if I step through it in the debugger slowly but I can't always replicate this.

What's going on? How can I get `{users && users.updated && <h1>Text rendered!</h1>}` to render properly on longer asynchronous calls?

Full code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  // 1. Get Data from API
  useEffect(() => {
      //----replicating asyncronous API call----
      //"Text rendered!" doesn't render if the timeout is large (700ms)
      //but does render if timeout is small (2ms)
      //(On codesandbox "Text rendered!" never renders, even if you don't use a timeout just use setUsers)
     
      setTimeout(() => setUsers({ data: ["user1", "user2", "user3"] }), 2);
  }, []);

  // 2. Once Data is Receive from API, Transform It
  useEffect(() => {
    if (users) {
      const usersCopy = users;

      usersCopy.updated = true;

      setUsers(usersCopy);
    }
  }, [users]);

  // 3. After the Data is Transformed, Render "Text Rendered!" 
  return (
    <>
      Render text below:
      {users && users.updated && <h1>Text rendered!</h1>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The main problem is this: `const usersCopy = users;` You're supposed to do `const usersCopy = { ...users };` so it's a new object, otherwise React cannot detect the change. Also, setting users inside a useEffect with a [users] dependency creates an infinite loop. Doc ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: Thanks! Changing to `if (users && !users.updated) {const usersCopy = { ...users };` solved it!